# I want percentage of matched records in Laravel search query. Suppose for first user three search parameter matched etc then how can i get percentage

Tags: php, laravel

I have a user table and i am searching with 5 request parameter with multiple where like query.I want percentage of matched records in Laravel search query. Suppose for first user three search column matched , for second user 5 column matched then how can i get count or percentage of each user matched?

Please help me. I want to show the user matched % (Ex. User1-20% matched, User1-100% matched)

My Query

```
$searchJobSeeker = DB::table('users')
    ->join('job_seekers_details', 'job_seekers_details.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('users.role', '=', 'job_seeker')
    ->where('job_seekers_details.position', 'like', '%'. $userDetails->companydetails->position .'%')
    ->orwhere('job_seekers_details.contract_length', 'like', '%'. $userDetails->companydetails->contract_length)
    ->orwhere('job_seekers_details.industry', 'like', '%'. $userDetails->companydetails->industry)
    ->orwhere('job_seekers_details.salary', '=', $userDetails->companydetails->salary)
    ->orwhere('job_seekers_details.willing_to_relocate', '=', $userDetails->companydetails->willing_to_relocate)
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

Comment: You can add foreach() on your results and check every column you are matching using Str::contains();

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding foreach on your results, like this :

```
$matchRates = [];
foreach($searchJobSeeker as $seeker){
   $rate = 0;
   // All your rate calculations here, like the one below ...
   $rate += Str::contains($seeker->position, $userDetails->companydetails->position) ? 20 : 0;
   $matchRates[$seeker->id] = $rate;
}
```